# Redirect from default azure domain

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm running an .NET Core 3.1 website (C#, Windows) on Azure (namewebsite.azurewebsites.net). I can't find any solution to redirect all traffic from namewebsite.azurewebsites.net to www.example.com. For example: when someone is visiting https://namewebsite.azurewebsites.net/profile/data, a permanent redirect should accomplished to https://www.example.com/profile/data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i'm unsure about the exact requirements, but when it comes to redirecting, What you could do is edit the computes `host.txt` file and add a redirect there,

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

```
127.0.0.1  https://namewebsite.azurewebsites.net/profile/data
```

https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/edit-windows-hosts-file-to-block-redirect-websites/

Answer (score 0):

You would have normally accomplished this by defining rewrite rules in your web.config evaluating the HTTP_HOST with a regex and a redirect action.

```
<system.webServer>  
<rewrite>  
    <rules>  
      <rule name=“Origin URL Redirect stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />  
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^namewebsite\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" />  
      </rule>  
    </rules>  
</rewrite>
```

In ASP.NET Core you can still achieve that via the [URL Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1). It will also help if you need to cover your non-www subdomain requests.

Another option, based on additional needs like WAF, consider using [Azure Front Door](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview) in front of your App Service and only allow traffic to your app service from Front Door.